# Facebook with android - Get ID

Tags: android, facebook

I have a line of code

```
String id = facebook.request("me");
        System.out.println(id);
```

This returns all the details but i was wondering how to return Just the ID of the person?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: show us what are you getting  in your println.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(authenticatedFacebook.request("me"));    
String id =jObject.getString("id");
```

This will returns the Id of the Logged User..Similarly you can get all data by replacing the Tag Name..

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Lena's answer is more efficient, and can work, but is missing one bit... The fields=id should be passed as a new Bundle object. Then you only get the ID in the response from Facebook.

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("fields", "id");
AsyncFacebookRunner asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
asyncRunner.request("me", bundle, new AsyncFacebookRunner.RequestListener() {
            public void onMalformedURLException(MalformedURLException e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onIOException(IOException e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onFileNotFoundException(FileNotFoundException e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e, Object state) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onComplete(String response, Object state) {
                JSONObject jObject;
                try {
                    jObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    Log.d("FACEBOOK ID", jObject.getString("id"));

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

[In the documentation](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/) it says that you can request `"me?fields=id"` instead of `"me"` so that only the needed data is transmitted.

However, using the Android API `mAsyncRunner.request("me?fields=id", ...)` results in the following error, even when under the same circumstances `"me"` works fine:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 2500
  }
}
```

So I guess getting the whole bunch of information and extracting the ID as Venky explained is the best way.